# How many multiple "Eclipse Projects" is considered too excessive for one actual development project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently working on a project that contains many different Eclipse projects referencing each other to make up one large project.  Is there a point where a developer should ask themselves if they should rethink the way their development project is structured?

**NOTE:** My project currently contains 25+ different Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is I would create a new project for every reusable component. So for example if I have some isolated functionality that can be packaged say as a jar, I would create a new project so I can build,package and distribute the component independently.

Also, if there are certain projects that you do not need to make frequent changes to, you can build them only when required and keep them "closed" in eclipse to save time on indexing, etc. Even if you think that a certain component is not reusable, as long as it is separated from the rest of the code base in terms of logic/concerns you may be well served by just separating it out. Sometimes seemingly specific code might be reusable in another project or in a future version of the same project.

Comment: Some of them are, but I would say probably about 75% of them are not reusable on their own.

Comment: Ryan- see my response in the second paragraph.

Comment: @neesh - I see.  I should have said they're not separated in terms of logic.

Answer (score 4):

When compiled, a project would typically result in a jar. So if your application consists of potentially reusable components, it is ok to use a project for each.

I'm a big fan of using a lot of projects, I feel that this "breaks down" large things beyond what I can do with packages, and helps me orient and navigate.

Of course, if you're developing Eclipse plug-ins, everything would be a project anyway.

The only thing I would watch out for has to do with your source-control and it's ability to handle moves of files between projects. Subclipse had been giving me trouble with it, or maybe it's my SVN server that did.

Answer (score 4):

If your project has *that* many sub-projects, or modules, needed to actually compose your final artifact then it is time to look at having something like Maven and setting up a multi-module project.  It will a) allow you to work on each module independently without ide worries and allow easy setup in your ide (and others' IDEs) through the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` goal.  In addition, when building your entire top level project, maven will be able to derive from list of dependencies you have described what modules need to be built in what order.

[Here's a quick link via google](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) and a l[ink to the book Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://books.sonatype.com/maven-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-weather.html), which will explain things in much better detail in chapter 6 (once you have the basics).

This will also force your project to not be explicitly tied to Eclipse.  Being able to build independent from an ide means that any Joe Schmoe can come along and easily work with your code base using whatever tools he/she needs.

Answer (score 2):

Create jars for the projects you don't work in often. That should greatly reduce the clutter. If you work on all the projects often, then you can add targets to your build that will jar up the respective projects for you, which condenses everything down to one file that you can then include on the class path.

Answer (score 2):

An additional method is to create many different workspaces.  The benefit of separate workspaces is that you can remove some of the visual clutter/ performance overhead of having lots of projects.  You can use targets to jar up all of you projects and put them in a repository so you can reference them in each workspace.

Answer (score 1):

At a former job the entire application was more then +170 projects. While it was rarely necessary to have all projects checked out locally, even the 30-40 projects constantly in our scope made reindexing, etc. very slow.

Comment: To be honest I could not remember if it was 170 or 270 projects so I erred on the safe side. But like I said, we didn't need all projects checked out locally.

Comment: lol, that is amazing :D Why so many projects? Do any of them have more than 20 classes?

Answer (score 1):

Yeesh. One Project for each Project. If you are using reusable projects, make them into a library for heavens sake. Break the none re-usable projects into packages, that's what they are there for.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard question and answers span from having one eclipse project at all to having one eclipse project for every single class.

My bottomline:

1. You can have too few projects,
   and never too many (of course use
   automation e.g. mvn eclipse:eclipse)
2. Use
   -Declipse.useProjectReferences=true/false
   when using maven to switch workspace
   mode btw jar and project
   dependencies
3. Use mvn release plugin to generate
   consecutive releases (automatic
   version increase)
4. Multiple projects gives you
   independent versioning which is
   ***extremely*** important. E.g. one dev may work on a new version of a
   module while you still depends on
   the previous one and you at some
   point decide to upgrade to the newer
   version(possibly by increasing its version in pom.xml dependency section). Or in other scenario if one
   project contains a bug you downgrade
   to its previous version.
5. Multiple projects makes you think
   about the architecture more than if
   you have just packages.
6. Multiple projects generally make
   architectural problems evident more
   than if you have just one project.
   Anyone would like to comment on
   this?
7. You never know if you project
   evolves into OSGI/SOA/EDA where you
   need separation.
8. Even if you're 100% sure that you
   projects will be deployed as one jar
   in an old way in a single jvm, it
   still does not hurt(mvn assembly
   plugin) to have multiple eclipse
   projects for logically independent
   pieces of code

BTW, the project I work on is divided into 24 eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hell, we have more than 100. Projects don't cost anything.